# RatingBar deosn't show exact rating

Tags: java, android, listview, rating, ratingbar

I've added `RatingBar` to each item of my `ListView`. It works well but it doesn't show **exact rating**. For example if the rating is 4.3 it has to show part of the 5th star, but it **DOESN'T**.

*Screenshot*:

- Rating of the first item = 4.3
- Rating of the second item = 4.5

[image: My current ListView]

Do you have any idea, where the problem could be?

I'd be glad for any help or suggestion.

**ratingsbar.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_star_rate1" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_star_rate1" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_star_rate" />
</layer-list>
```

**Method in the getView() in my adapter**

```
if(clubs.getInt("clubRating")!= 0){
        holder.rating.setRating((float) (clubs.getInt("clubRating"))); 
        }else{
            holder.rating.setRating(0); 
        }
```

**item layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:minHeight="220dp"
    android:background="@drawable/club_item"
    android:id="@+id/clubAll" >


   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club_poster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club_vip_small"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/club_events_true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:text="@string/events_true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#00C659"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/eventsup" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/club_discounts_true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/discounts_true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/club_events_true"
        android:background="#F6D100"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/golden_discount" />


    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:minHeight="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/club_head_info" >


     <com.example.android.ImageViewRounded
        android:id="@+id/club_club_logo"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_club"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


     <com.example.android.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/club_distance_small"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:background="@drawable/meters_back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

     <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/club_club_logo"
    android:id="@+id/club_foot_info" >

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/club_type_fake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bar"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/type_btn_bar" />

         <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/club_typerate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/club_type_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bar"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/type_btn_bar" />

      <RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/club_rating_small"
      android:padding="1dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/club_type_small"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:isIndicator="true"
      android:stepSize="0.01"
      android:numStars="5"
      style="@style/foodRatingBar"    
           />

      </RelativeLayout>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/club_title_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ROXY Prague"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/club_type_fake"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/club_openclose_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:text="@string/open"
        android:textColor="#00AC00"
        android:layout_below="@id/club_title_small"
         />


      </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `clubs.getInt("clubRating")` it must be giving int value, i.e.4, right?

Comment: Please refresh my question. The items have values of 4.3 and 4.5. Thats where the problem is

Comment: I am telling u to debug over here: `holder.rating.setRating((float) (clubs.getInt("clubRating"))); ` . `getInt` returns int value. so it can't be 4.3 or 4.5 but just 4. Please  Recheck. You should save float value and get float value. Then `setRating` should work properly.

Comment: You were true! It return wrong values. Thank you for your help

Comment: Great. happy coding :) Always debug before posting question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()`, you request the rating as an integer and then cast it to a float. Therefore the decimal values are lost. Store a float value instead and then use `getFloat`:

```
holder.rating.setRating(clubs.getFloat("clubRating"));
```